# hammer.js, prevent "tap" from firing on "doubletap"

Tags: hammer.js

I have the following setup

```
function hammerIt(elm) {
    hammertime = new Hammer(elm, {});
    hammertime.on('tap doubletap pan pinch panstart panend pinchend swipe swipeleft swiperight swipedown swipeup', function(ev) {

        // Doesn't work...
        var doubletap = hammertime.get('doubletap');
        var tap = hammertime.get('tap');
        doubletap.recognizeWith(tap);
        tap.requireFailure(doubletap);

        if (ev.type == 'tap') {
            doSomething();
        }

        if (ev.type == 'doubletap') { // This is never fired....
            doSomethingElse();
        }

        // etc.
}
```

When I doubletap/-click on the element, both the tap and the doubletap event are fired. I only want the doubletap to fire but somehow my code doesn't work? Is it because I'm using on(events) and .get("event name") instead of dedicated events like in the example on https://hammerjs.github.io/require-failure/ or am I missing something else?

Comment: check this example with working single/double-tap https://jsfiddle.net/michabeeri/g91qx4bq/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you john Smith, based on your fiddle I've come up with a working solution:

```
function hammerIt(elm) {
    hammertime = new Hammer.Manager(elm);

    var doubletap = new Hammer.Tap({event: 'doubletap', taps: 2});
    var tap = new Hammer.Tap({event: 'tap'});
    var pan = new Hammer.Pan();
    var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch({enable:true});
    var swipe = new Hammer.Swipe();

    hammertime.add([doubletap, tap, pan, pinch, swipe]);

    hammertime.get('tap').requireFailure('doubletap');

    hammertime.on('tap doubletap pan pinch panstart panend pinchend swipe swipeleft swiperight swipedown swipeup', function(ev) {
        if (ev.type == 'tap') {
            doSomething();
        }

        if (ev.type == 'doubletap') {
            doSomethingElse();
        }

        // etc.
    }
}
```

I think the problem was using "new Hammer(elem..." instead of a "new Hammer.Manager(elem)". This way I have to add the recognizers manually instead of using the default set but at least it works as expected :-)